# Google Api client is not connected yet in Android 10,

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, geolocation, location

Google Api client is not connected yet in Android 10, I have searched but didn't get a suitable answer any one please here to help me out.
Here is my stack-trace.

**
java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zaak.execute(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:129)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabe.execute(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:23)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zaaw.execute(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:74)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.location.zzq.requestLocationUpdates(Unknown Source:14)
at com.example.offeruppro.Fragments.Post.LocationFragment.onConnected(LocationFragment.java:433)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.GmsClientEventManager.onConnectionSuccess(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:33)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zaaw.zab(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:292)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zaak.zaao(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:125)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zaak.onConnected(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:105)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabe.onConnected(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:101)
at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zap.onConnected(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:6)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zaf.onConnected(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@17.1.0:2)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzg.zzj(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.1.1:24)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zza.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.1.1:12)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzb.zzo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.1.1:11)
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.BaseGmsClient$zzc.handleMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.1.1:49)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.common.zzi.dispatchMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.1.1:8)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8178)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1101)

**

Comment: First: post in such a way that the lines are conserved. Its unreadable now.

Comment: Google Api client is not connected yet in Android 10, I have searched but didn't get a suitable answer any one please here to help me out.

Comment: you should post your GoogleApiClient creation logic? From stack trace it looks like an issue in your client creation.